# How to install anbox on a pure debian system

Tags: linux, debian, deb

Ok, I know it's not supported fully on debian yet, but is there anyway to run anbox (anbox.io) on a debian installation. Since It runs on ubuntu, I assume it would be possible on debian.

Comment: Anbox isn't available as a binary package for Debian yet. You'll have to compile it from source. The Readme file in the GitHub repo has all the instructions.

Comment: I have attempted that with the system I want to run it on, but my cmake can't recognize my -dbus-cpp-dev no matter what I do, would it be possible to compile anbox on another system I have then move it back to the original system and use make and make install? Sorry, I'm new to compiling from source

Comment: Probably not. Each distribution tends to name the libraries differently, so the resulting binary may not be able to find the necessary libraries when run in a different distro. I don't know how you've set up your environment, so I have to ask. Have you installed `libdbus-c++-dev`? that's what the package is called in Debian. You should revise your question and provide sufficient details of what you've tried and the exact problem you're having. You'll have better chance of getting helpful answers that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use snapd. anbox is only available as snaps.

Install snapd :

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

and install (& run) anbox:

```
sudo snap install --classic anbox-installer && anbox-installer
```

Comment: lo, forgot this was open, it was not possible to install via that method, you must do that ( if you can get snapd installed) which fights alot, then you must manually put in the correct kernels as anbox does not recognize a pure debian system as being compatible and will not fetch the kernel via snapd. So you must also edit the anbox-installer before any of this will even work, since anbox installer does not accept pure debian systems.

Comment: Actually for `unstable` there is now `anbox:amd64 0.0~git20181210-1`, run on a lxc container, no need to install snap

Comment: Starting `anbox-installer` shows a warning that this is deprecated. One should now install `anbox` instead (Debian 10).

Comment: Since Buster `sudo apt install anbox`.

Comment: Outdated answer. Use the official Debian package.

Comment: At least for debian-unstable("sid"), Mar 2021, i had to run: `sudo snap install anbox --beta --devmode`.

Answer (score 8):

On Debian Sid, there is a package for Anbox: https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/anbox

The package sets everything up in the kernel (module `binder_linux`, `ashmem`), and sets up a systemd service (`anbox-container-manager`).

However, the package does not contain any android image expected in `/var/lib/anbox/android.img`, this image has to be taken from `https://build.anbox.io/android-images/` or from an existing snap installation in `/var/snap/anbox/android.img`.

Once, the image is installed, run:

- **as root**: `service  anbox-container-manager start`
- **as normal user** (in a first terminal): `anbox session-manager`
- **as normal user** (in a second terminal): `anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr --component=org.anbox.appmgr.AppViewActivity`

(There may be a refresh bug, move the cursor within the anbox graphical window)

See [Debian documentation in `/usr/share/doc/anbox/README.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/zhsj/anbox/blob/master/debian/README.Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Install snapd:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

and install (& run) anbox:

```
sudo snap install --classic anbox-installer && anbox-installer
```

You may get an error (`bash: anbox-installer: command not found`) if you are on raspbian desktop like I was.

Once, snapd installed and configured, run the following command to install snap store app.

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question.  This post is really a comment on the accepted answer rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I was allready done with the snapd install and setup. When I saw anbox in 'Sid'. For me, "snap install --classic anbox-installer"was the correct command. (Anbox.io instructions fail to mention  --classic). Everything was okay but the DKMS modules didn't work.

I enabled 'sid' repositories and updated to the latest LTS kernel to get ashmem and binder. Now every time I want to run anbox I need to type "modprobe ashmem-linux" and "modprobe binder-linux", but that can be automated and I think it works for now.

But as a starting point for newcomers, I guess that anbox:amd64 in 'sid' is the best way.

Regards,
Blackslide